# OOP Python card game class methods

Tags: python, oop

I have written a simple card game where upon initialising the game each player is given two cards.

At the bottom I have created a method called returnCards that puts the cards of a player back in the deck.

I am new to OOP in python and am curious if it's good convention to create a standalone method like this?

I feel as though this method should actually be a Player class method but I'm unsure how to write it as such. More than anything I'm trying to understand good practices when writing OOP code

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for i in ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"]:
            for j in range(1,14):
                self.cards.append(Card(i, j))

    def length(self):
        return len(self.cards)

class Game:
    def __init__(self, players, deck):
        self.players = players
        self.deck = deck
        self.cards = deck.cards

    def deal(self):
        for player in self.players:
            for i in range(2):
                player.cards.append(self.drawCard())

    def drawCard(self):
        drawnCard = self.deck.cards[0]
        self.deck.cards = self.deck.cards[1:]
        return drawnCard

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cards = []


def returnCards(player, game):
    game.deck.cards.append(card for card in player.cards)
    player.cards = []


deckOfCards = Deck()
playerOne = Player("John")
playerTwo = Player("Harrry")
newGame = Game([playerOne, playerTwo], deckOfCards)
newGame.deal()
returnCards()
```

Comment: Card, Deck, and Player classes seem reasonable, although perhaps missing some attributes/methods you will need.  Game seems off.  Does a game need both a deck, and cards?  Should there be some concept of a "turn"?  If yes, how can you model that? Should each player get the same cards every time the game is started?  Hopefully some questions to get you on the right track.

Comment: I assume you're using 1 for an Ace, 11 for Jack, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider having two `return_cards` methods, on `Player` and `Deck`

```
class Player:

    ...

    def return_cards(self, deck):
        deck.return_cards(self.cards)
        self.cards = []


class Deck:

    ...

    def return_cards(self, cards):
        self.cards.extend(cards)
```

The idea is that objects handle their own responsibilities -they do things to themselves - rather than managing other objects' responsibilities.  So `Player` is responsible for returning its cards to `Deck`, and `Deck` is responsible for what happens to the cards once they have been returned.

Another consideration is that we don't want objects to know too much about each others internals.

```
game.deck.cards.append(card for card in player.cards)
```

means that `Game` "knows" that `Deck` has a list named `cards`.  This kind of design is couples objects to tightly - if `Deck.cards` becomes a set or a dict we have to change `Game` - it's better to access cards via methods rather than directly.  See also [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) and the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

`Game` would be responsible for telling `Player` that it's time to return the hand.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and is definitely going to help me to write clearer code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using separately defined functions is ok, but only when the function is not related and strongly tied with the objects (formatters etc.).

In your case it actually should be a method of Game class at it is basically a new game beginning. Take a look of how it might look with some tips in comments:

```
from collections import deque
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val

    # good practice is to include repr and str magic methods - that way you can print meaningful info
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} {}>'.format(self.value, self.suit)


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        # use deque - it's more efficient to pop from left than from a list -> good advice -> learn build in types :)
        self.cards = deque()
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.cards.clear()
        for i in ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"]:
            for j in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(i, j))
        # need to shuffle in order to have random order of cards
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def length(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def get_card(self):
        return self.cards.popleft()

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Deck: [{} Cards]'.format(self.length())


class Game:
    def __init__(self, players, deck):
        self.players = players
        self.deck = deck

    def deal(self):
        for player in self.players:
            for i in range(2):
                player.give_card(self.draw_card())

    # in python use underscore not camelCase for methods
    def draw_card(self):
        # avoid mutating other object properties in other objects
        return self.deck.get_card()

    def restart_game(self):
        # simply rebuild the deck - it will reshuffle all cards
        self.deck.build()
        for player in self.players:
            player.return_cards()


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cards = []

    def give_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def return_cards(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Player: {} - [{}]'.format(self.name, ','.join([str(x) for x in self.cards]))


deck_of_cards = Deck()
player_one = Player("John")
player_two = Player("Harrry")
new_game = Game([player_one, player_two], deck_of_cards)
new_game.deal()
print(player_one, player_two)
print(new_game.deck)
new_game.restart_game()
print(player_one, player_two)
print(new_game.deck)
```

If for some reason not stated here you want to keep the original card objects (i.e. to count how many times the card was drawn etc.) you can follow @snakecharmerb answer (methods in deck and player) and I would handle the logic behind this in Game class (that way you don't need player and deck referencing each other, and it is more logical from the business perspective)

Comment: I didn't know about deque so that's definitely something useful to know. Presumably then if I wanted to create a stack in python then deque would be the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: @PIEAGE Yes, deque is optimized for both appending and popping the elements from both sides. I recommend getting used to builtin collections, itertools and functools as it contains a lot of useful code

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute right and wrong when doing OOP. It's just a conceptual philosophy which helps you organize your code to achieve maintainability and sustainability.

You will do a lot of refactoring works in the future when the use case changes(it will always change). The changing use case may also affect how you organize your `return_cards` method.

So all you have to worry about is how the code PRESENTLY look like, is it understandable enough to you and to people you are working with? Again, there is no absolute answer.

Here is my opinion.

- Having a global `return_cards` function seems not reasonable. You are mixing two types of philosophy, procedural programming and object-oriented programming,  together, while provides very limited clues and boundary to explain why it goes this way.
- PRESENTLY, I think `return_cards()` could only locate in the `Game` class. Since either `Deck` and `Player` can be regarded as the status of the `Game`. So let the **method** of the Game change the **status** of Game, it's perfectly understandable.
- Of course, you can do something like this:

```
class Game:
    ......
    def return_cards(self):
        for player in self.players:
            player_cards = self.players.give_all_cards_back()
            self.decks.collect_all_cards(player_cards)
```

but I don't think it's necessary PRESENTLY. When will it be? For example, when some other modules, such as UI or some text-printing procedure, are depending on your `Player` object, you have to notify them when players return back their card. Then it's reasonable to create something like `Player.give_all_cards_back()` and encapsulate all the related procedure together.

Here is some sample code from Ramalho's *Fluent Python* (O'Reilly), demonstrating how to build a `Deck` class, for your reference.

```
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple("Card", ("rank", "suit"))

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list("JQKA")
    suits = "spades diamonds clubs hearts".split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
```